# "Unknown column" error in a join query designed to select a single row within groups of interest

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

May I know why I am getting error

> Unknown column 'wp_postmeta.post_ID' in 'field list'

Here are the tables in question:

```
create table wp_posts (
  ID integer primary key auto_increment,
  post_title varchar(30),
  post_type varchar(30)
);

create table wp_postmeta (
  ID integer primary key auto_increment,
  post_id integer,
  meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
  meta_value integer not null
);

insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
('Apple Pie','Product'),
('French Toast','Product'),
('Shepards Pie','Product'),
('Jam Pie','Product'),
('Jam Pie','Product'),
('Plate','Not a Product'),
('Bucket','Not a Product'),
('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
('French Toast','Product'),
('French Toast','Product');

insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
(1,10),
(2,5),
(3,9),
(4,8),
(5,11),
(6,12),
(7,10),
(8,6),
(9,1),
(10,1);
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM (
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice
FROM wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
  WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
)
as x inner join 

(
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
  WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
)
 as f on x.post_title = f.post_title and f.meta_value = x.minprice
```

[fiddle with data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba0aa9a33f61d69171dfd5ab51d77a61)

In case you're interested, I'm adapting this code from [this tutorial](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) that will give you the context of what I am doing.

Comment: SELECT wp_postmeta.post_ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value - this entire statement is incorrect you need to use the alias names for these columns.

Comment: aliasing problem.

Comment: Well done for asking a clear and concise question - fantastically rare, unfortunately

Comment: @Strawberry thanks.  Appreciate the tips and feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use subquery alias name in selection as you used subquery

```
SELECT f.post_ID, x.post_title, f.meta_value
FROM (
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) AS minprice
FROM wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
  WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
)
as x inner join 

(
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta 
  JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_ID=wp_posts.ID
  WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
)
 as f on x.post_title = f.post_title and f.meta_value = x.minprice
```

[fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b799895f5a630ab56bd14c772e50481b)